# If $x^{2a-3} y^2 = x^{6-a} y^{5a}$ then $a\log(\frac{x}{y}) = ?$

Tags: logarithms

If $x^{2a-3} y^2 = x^{6-a} y^{5a}$ then $a\log(\frac{x}{y}) = ?$
[I have Tried this and stucked here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnuRv.jpg)

Comment: OP, please tell us the context for this question, and show us what work you've done to try to solve it.

Comment: Have you tried applying a logarithm to both sides of the equality that you were given?

Comment: Yeah i have applied Logarithm to both sides but i unable to get required answer.

Comment: @AkashSaxena `i have applied ...` You should edit your question and add what you tried and where you got stuck. That said, what makes you expect that there would be a unique answer?

Answer (score 1):

You are given
$x^{2a-3} y^2=x^{6-a} y^{5a}
$.
Multiplying by
$x^{a-6}y^{-2}
$,
this becomes
$x^{3a-9}=y^{5a-2}
$.

Looking at this,
I notice that,
if the
$y^2$
were
$y^{2a}$,
the right side would be
$y^{3a}$.
This indicates to me that
there might be
an error in
the statement of the problem.

However,
working with the problem
as written,
$(3a-9)\log x=(5a-2)\log y
$
so that
$\log y
=\frac{3a-9}{5a-2}\log x
$.

Therefore

$\begin{array}\\
a\log(x/y)
&=a(\log x-\log y)\\
&=a(\log x-\frac{3a-9}{5a-2}\log x)\\
&=\log x(a-\frac{3a-9}{5a-2})\\
&=a\log x(1-\frac{3a-9}{5a-2})\\
&=a\log x\frac{(5a-2)-(3a-9)}{5a-2}\\
&=a\log x\frac{2a+7}{5a-2}\\
\end{array}
$